# Error adding ListObject columns to Userform combobox List

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, userform, populate

I have a userform that I named UFCustInfo.  In the worksheet area, I have a macro to display the form -

```
Private Sub CmdShowInputForm()
    UFCustInfo.Show
End Sub
```

This is assigned to a button(form control) on the worksheet.

In the userform area, I also have an initialize routine to populate a combo box on the userform –

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
      Me.CBCustName.List = ActiveSheet.ListObject("CustInfo").ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.Value
End Sub
```

When I click the command button to display the form, I get Runtime Error ‘438’: Object does not support this property  or method , and debug highlights the “UFCustInfo.Show” line.

If I disable (comment) the Initialize line, the form will load but (of course) the combo box doesn’t populate.

I also have code to add new, clear form, and close form that all run fine as long as I don’t run the initialize code.  What am I missing?

Comment: What is "CustInfo"? What is name of your UserForm?

Comment: UFCustInfo is the name I gave the UserForm.  CustInfo is the name of the table and the name of the sheet in which the table resides.  So i think  ActiveSheet.ListObject("CustInfo") refers to the table.

Comment: You don't give much supporting information. I suspect it's where you're trying to fill the list with the 'table' but whaty is your 'table' - is it a rangename reference - or a real table object? How many rows/columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the limited information yor've supplied about your listobject, I think this fix might work for you. I think `ListObject` is a type and `ListObjects` (plural) is the collection you're trying to access.

```
' *Add this to top of your module to identify future syntax errors before running *'

Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Const COL_NUM as Integer = 1 ' Which column you want to access '

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    Dim tbl As ListObject

    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("CustInfo")

    CBCustName.Clear

    With tbl
       ' Add cell values one at a time to the Combo Box List
       For i = 1 To tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
           CBCustName.AddItem tbl.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, COL_NUM)
       Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you dbmitch for taking time to respond...I'll give that a go and let you know how it works out.

Comment: Hi dbmitch.  I added "Dim i As Long" and this works.  I've seen the construct I was trying before as a solution to populate a combobox, but I don't know why it doesn't work in this case.  I need to learn more about For/Next loops and this specifically: For i = 1 To tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count.  It appears we're assigning the number of rows in the table to i. Then we're adding the values for every row (from the first column) to CBCustName.  I don't think I've ever seen COL_NUM.  At any rate, I thank you very much for taking time to  help! Ha! Just noticed where you declared COL_NUM.

Comment: Sure - I can update that answer with a bit more information but it looks like you got it all figured out. Feel free to upvote my answer if it was useful or even mark it as an answer if it did the job

Comment: Excellent answer, and explanation.  I thank you again, and now I'll work on populating the other controls based on the customer name the user selects (address, city, state, zip, etc.)

Comment: Thanks - enjoy your coding!